# How to set UICollectionViewCell size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to change collectionViewCell size from

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

For this I do:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize = 1000
```

but it does not change the size at all. Also, I have the next function:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var newSize: CGSize?

    let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame)
    newSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + 100)

    return newSize!
}
```

So, how can I override it from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: You just need to override collection view delegate method `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` for setting collection view's cell size.

Comment: @RichardG how can I do it from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`? When I add `override` to `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` it rises an error `method does not override any method`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your project and then implement `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method to set size of collection view's cell.

Comment: XCode doesn't show the sizeForItemAt delegate method (and if i put it there as you've described, it isn't called). I'm not using a UICollectionViewController, but rather a ViewController of my own that has a UICollectionView in it. I've added the view controller as delegate for data source though, but still nothing.

Comment: Nvm, worked it out. Had to manually set data source and delegate in code (storyboard caused the issue)